# Mark multiple point to point zones on Canvas

Tags: angularjs

I am marking point to point zones on Canvas using Angularjs.
I want to close the zone once I click near the starting position of the zone and start a second new Zone. (To plot lines for zone I am just clicking on the Canvas)

[Current Working Principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lruQv.png) (Please click on link for attachment)

My HTML Part :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Example">
     <div>
          <canvas width="500" height="300" id="myCanvas" drawing ng-click="draw($event)" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
     </div>
</div>
```

My App.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("Example", function($scope, $interval) {
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  $scope.x;
  $scope.y;
  $scope.lastX = 0;
  $scope.lastY = 0;
  $scope.sw = 5;
  $scope.draw = function(e) {
    $scope.lastX = $scope.x;
    $scope.lastY = $scope.y;
    $scope.x = e.offsetX;
    $scope.y = e.offsetY;
    $scope.elements.push(
    {"x":$scope.x,
    "y":$scope.y,
    "lx":$scope.lastX,
    "ly":$scope.lastY}
    );
    ctx.moveTo($scope.lastX, $scope.lastY);
    ctx.lineTo($scope.x, $scope.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#4bf";
    ctx.stroke();         
  };
});
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by this. Do you actually want to start drawing from (0, 0), draw to ( 0, 10), draw to (10, 10), draw to (10, 0) and to have it automatically joined this (10, 0) with (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, sounds perfect..